# How to pin a batch file to the Taskbar (Quicklaunch)

Tags: windows-8

[Brian Borg's answer at technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/a44e74a1-20cd-4924-8f2b-3e6b688f1ad7/adding-batch-files-to-windows-7-taskbar-like-the-vistaxp-quick-launch?forum=w7itprou;") explains how to Pin a batch file to the Taskbar in Windows 7.  I was able to do that in Windows 7 and it worked fine.

But I'm unable to make it work in Windows 8. The explanation doesn't make the syntax clear for adding the path and filename of the batch file.  It's been several years since I did it in Windows 7 so I may not have done this part right, but I have tried every combination I can think of.

Here are a few examples I've tried:

```
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/C" C:\Users\[username]\winbats\dogbones.bat
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" "/C" "C:\Users\[username]\winbats\dogbones.bat"
"C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe" /C C:\Users\[username]\winbats\dogbones.bat
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C C:\Users\[username]\winbats\dogbones.bat
C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C "C:\Users\[username]\winbats\dogbones.bat"
```

They all open a command prompt, but none executed the batch file.

Does anyone know the correct syntax or another way to pin a batch file to the taskbar in Windows 8?

Comment: Not a duplicate since this question is for Windows 8

Comment: This is not a duplicate. How do we get it unmarked as a duplicate?

Answer (score 21):

**PIN to home screen (Start):**

1. Navigate to `%AppData%\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs`
2. Create a shortcut to your .bat script and rename it to how you want it to appear on start screen, i.e. `My Script`
3. Optional - change shortcut icon if you wish
4. Go to the Start Screen and search for the name you gave to your shortcut in step 2
5. Select `My Script` and click on `Pin to Start` or `Pin to taskbar`

**And this will allow both home screen (Start) and taskbar:**

1. Right click on your `Desktop` and choose `New` > `Shortcut`
2. In the Type the location of the item field enter: `cmd.exe /c "path\to\script.bat"`
3. Replace `path\to\script.bat` with actual path to your .bat file.
4. Click `Next`, name the shortcut and click `Finish`.

The pinning:

- To Pin the .bat file to the `Start` home screen, right click the new shortcut and choose `Pin to Start`.
- To Pin the .bat file to the taskbar, simply drag the shortcut to your Windows taskbar, or right click the new shortcut and choose `Pin to Taskbar`.

Comment: Important to note if you just launch the new shortcut, and right click it's icon on the taskbar and then click 'pin to taskbar' it won't work. You have to choose the 'pin to taskbar' option available by right clicking on the shortcut itself.